# HIbernate: java.sql.BatchUpdateException when persisting new object

Tags: java, docker, hibernate

In my project I have two entities **Milestone** and **TipoLotto**, which are connected by a @ManyToOne/@OneToMany relation.
This is what I've got in **Milestone**:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "LOTTO")
private TipoLotto lotto;
```

That's the inverse relation in TipoLotto:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lotto", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Milestone> milestone;
```

In a portion of my code, I get all records from TipoLotto table on database and insert them in a map, whose keys are primary keys on table and objects are corresponding TipoLotto entities:

```
Map<String, TipoLotto> mappaLotti = gestionaleDAO.getLottiPerChiave();
```

Later on, I create a new Milestone, get a TipoLotto object from map according to a key, insert it into new Milestone and save Milestone using **save** method from repository

```
public interface MilestoneRepository extends JpaRepository<Milestone, Long>
```

This sequence of actions saves without any problem my new **Milestone** on database and correctly links new record to TipoLotto table through a foreing key.
Strangely, when we moved application to Azure DevOps, executing it inside a Docker machine, the saving operation caused the following exception:

```
    HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SAL.PK_TIPO_LOTTO) violated
], SQL: insert into tipo_lotto (descrizione, nominativo, id_lotto) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Hibernate seems to be adding a new record to TipoLotto, but it shouldn't since the ID of entity already exists on DB. Am I right?
My local application and its deployment on DevOps use same database.
Does anyone have an idea about the cause of such problem and different behaviours on two environments?

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a transaction for the whole process? If not, Hibernate will just see the `TipoLotto` objects as new and try to persist them due to your cascading configuration. If you want separate transactions, you have to use `Repository.getOne` which uses `EntityManager.getReference` behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks for you answer. The creation of a Milestone (and the insertion of a TipoLotto inside of it) is repeated N times. So, my function creates a list of Milestones and forwards it to a DAO method, which performs the save action and is labelled with Transactional annotation, since I want either all Milestones or none to be saved. Is thhis the transaction you are talking about? Would you move Transactional to the function that creates the list of Milestones?

Comment: The transaction should contain at least `gestionaleDAO.getLottiPerChiave();` and the call to `milestoneRepository.save()`